# I need to make a break page inside the abstract, because the result it show it like the image (latex - elsarticle)

Tags: latex

I don't know why elsarticle doesn't make breaks page in frontmatter automatically when is necessary.
also thanks to the above, first page's header and footer don't appear.

[image]

I tried use `\newpage` inside abstract, also `\newpage` afer
but simply but is ignored by elsarticle

Really I don't know how to separate in pages abstract

Code:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Latin American Neurointensive Care Journal}
\setlength{\footskip}{2cm}
\fancyfoot[R]{Merenciano}

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Latin American Neurointensive Care Journal}
    \fancyhead[R]{Merenciano A.}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Merenciano}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Línea horizontal para el encabezado
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Línea horizontal para el pie de página
}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
    \let\@oddhead\@empty
    \let\@evenhead\@empty
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \let\@evenfoot\@empty

}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\kms}{km\,s$^{-1}$}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}
     
        \title{Thoracic spine fracture secondary to anterior mediastinal yolk sac germ cell tumor: A case report and a brief review \\
        Fractura de columna torácica secundaria a tumor de células germinativas del saco vitelino del mediastino anterior: reporte de un caso y breve revisión\\
        Fratura de coluna torácica secundária a tumor de células germinativas do saco vitelino do mediastino anterior: relato de caso e breve revisão}
        
        \author[1]{Ana Carolina Merenciano Sundfeld Pereira}
        \author[2]{Carolina Mulet Reitor}
        \author[1]{José Victor Ribeiro Silva Gomes}
        \author[2]{Letícia Pinto Andrigheto}
        \author[3]{Leonardo Jardim Vaz de Mello}
        \author[4]{Ludmila Leite Sant`Anna Vaz de Mello}

        \affiliation[1]{
            organization={Universidade Federal de São João DelRei (UFSJ) Campus Dom Bosco},
            addressline={}, 
            city={São João del-Rei},
            postcode={}, 
            state={},
            country={Brazil}}

        \affiliation[2]{
        organization={Centro Universitário de Valença (UNIFAA)},
        city={Valença},
        country={Brazil}
        }

        \affiliation[3]{
        organization={profesor of Universidade Federal de Sao Joao Del Rei(UFSJ)},
        city={Sao Joao del Rei},
        country={Brazil}
        }

        \affiliation[4]{
        organization={Plastic Surgeon of Santa Casa da Misericordia},
        city={Sao Joao del Rei},
        country={Brazil}
        }

        %\address[first]{Hospital de urgéncias, %Córdoba..Argentina \\
        %Phanke Perla Blanca\\
        %\faEnvelope{ }perlapahnke@hotmail.com}
 
        \abstracttitle{}
        \begin{abstract}
        
            \noindent
            \textbf{Abstract}
                \lipsum[3-5]
                
            \medskip
            \noindent
            \textbf{Resumen}
                \lipsum[3-5]
              
            \medskip
            \noindent
            \textbf{Resumo}
                \lipsum[3-5]

             
        \end{abstract}
        
        \begin{keyword}
                %% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword, up to a maximum of 6 keywords
                Nonseminomatous \sep germ cell tumors \sep mediastinal tumor \sep yolk sac tumor \sep vertebral fracture
                
                %% PACS codes here, in the form: \PACS code \sep code
                
                %% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
                %% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)

        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
    \thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}
```